# Magento does not load CSS and Js

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1

My Magento website can't load CSS and Js and it is shown in the form of the attached image.

Link to the website: http://www.goharshad.af/

Any help will be highly appreciated on this problem.

Thanks.
[image: This is what I get.]

Comment: From what i see styles-m.css is loading fine.  Are you missing css and js files from head that would normally be there?  Did this happen out of the blue or did you push a change and then this occurred?  Try to be more specific.

Comment: Actually, I had a zipped backup in my PC of all the files of Public_html, I tried   uploading it back to public_html while I have deleted all the files which were already in public_html.

Comment: The admin panel works fine but the customer view is just coming in this above form where the styles of Mega Menu and the Sliders are all gone.

Comment: it might be file permission, and/or cache issue